# How to parse a Javascript file and get all the used variables?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I am gathering a lot of Javascript code from untrusted people and have to integrate it in my project. As is is untrusted, I would like to check if it doesn't do something nasty.

My main concern is the variables the code uses. 
To check it is OK, I would like to parse all the code and verify the name of the variables. For instance, that all the variables are included in `window.sandboxedVariables`.

Is it possible to parse a Javascript code (in any language but preferably Javascript or bash) and get the list of all the variables ? Is it possible to do the same with the imported libraries ?

Is it possible to do with Uglify ? I read a bit the API documentation and found nothing specific.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Variables exists per context

Comment: what about `window['ev' + 'al']('sandboxed' + 'Variables = null')`?

Comment: untrusted client code does not give access to untrusted tokens or passwords. How could that ever be a problem as long as you prevent xss?

Comment: Than do not use untrusted code....Easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mozilla Rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino). It is a JavaScript engine written in Java.

Here you can find an example similar to what you are trying to do:

http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/parsing-javascript-code-using-mozilla-rhino/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about global variables, you can do the following:

- clone the `window` object
- load/run the untrusted script
- compare the `window` object to the cloned one
- move all newfound items into `window.sandboxedVariables`

However, this won't work if the untrusted script overrides one of the existing properties (variables) of `window`.

Answer (score 0):

eslint is a JavaScript source code linting tool that lets you write custom plugins. You should be able to write a plugin that meets your needs. Plus, the plugins can be written in JavaScript.

http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to write an algorithm that verifies untrusted JavaScript code. You can parse it, you can run it in a sandbox and analyze its actions. But you can never be sure you've identified everything it might do or every variable it might use once you run it in your real environment.

If you don't trust it then either only run it in a secure sandbox or don't use it.